# Why converting a date to a string changes the order?

Tags: vb.net, string, date

Here is a peculiar result generated from this simple code:

```
Dim TodaysDate As Date = Date.Today ' Returns #8/12/2014#
Dim StringDate As String = TodaysDate ' Returns 12/08/2014
Dim AnotherStringDate As String = TodaysDate.ToString ' Returns 12/08/2014 00:00:00
```

What is going on? Why the string reversed the result, although I did not even used any conversion command?

Comment: Change `Option Strict` to `On`, then you get a compiler error instead of weird conversions. In general, a `Date` is not a `String` but it can be represented as a string. Then your currect culture is used to format it.

Comment: I know. I just wonder why this is happening :)

Comment: I asssume because the helper method VB is using uses `Date.ToShortDateString`(or `ToString("d")`) and your current culture uses this format.

Comment: what do you mean in the comment that the date var "Returns #8/12/2014#" returns it how/where?  If you set a breakpoint on an executable line after that, what does VS show on the mouse over display?

Comment: That is exactly what I did - I set a breakpoint and watched what VS showed...

Comment: I think your local culture uses 'd/m/y' so that is how the strings are built.  Date.Today is showing it in CultureInvariant form, the same order you would use to create a Date using a literal: `myDate = #8/12/2014#` it is also the order some of the VB functions require it.  They all mean the same thing - if you do a roundtrip and convert one of the strings to date, it should say the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `Option Strict` to `On`, then you get a compiler error instead of weird conversions. In general, a `Date` is not a `String` but it can be represented as one.

If i remember correctly VB uses helper methods with `Option Strict Off` to convert the type automatically which are sitting in the namespace `Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices`.

I've looked at the source-code (with `ILSpy`) and found a class `StringType` which has a method `FromDate`:

```
' Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.StringType
Public Shared Function FromDate(Value As DateTime) As String
    Dim ticks As Long = Value.TimeOfDay.Ticks
    If ticks = Value.Ticks OrElse (Value.Year = 1899 AndAlso Value.Month = 12 AndAlso Value.Day = 30) Then
        Return Value.ToString("T", Nothing)
    End If
    If ticks = 0L Then
        Return Value.ToString("d", Nothing)
    End If
    Return Value.ToString("G", Nothing)
End Function
```

Since your `Date` was derived from `Date.Today` which is the current date without time, the code will be executed which starts with `If ticks = 0L Then`(`ticks` is from the time of the day).

This returns:

```
Value.ToString("d", Nothing)
```

which is the same as [`Date.ToShortDateString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring(v=vs.110).aspx). The format is derived from your current culture since `null` is passed as `CultureInfo`. So obviously your current culture uses `/` as date separator.

You could also force this format by using:

```
Dim StringDate As String = TodaysDate.ToString("d")
StringDate = TodaysDate.ToShortdateString()
StringDate = TodaysDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

The last option also ensures that this format is used even if your current culture is different.

Answer (score 0):

A date is stored internally as number. And a date/datetime variable doesn't really know or care what actual date it represents; it is just a number (decimal). The string representation is for our eyes only. When you convert a date/datetime variable to string type, it is converted in the format specified by our machine locale settings, unless we specifically tell it to convert it to some other format.

I am assuming that the date/time settings on your PC is in the dd/mm/yyyy (indian format) format rather than the default mm/dd/yyyy (US format).

So this is what is actually happening:

```
    ' You store today's date in a Date variable and it returns #8/12/2014# i.e. 12-Aug-2014
    Dim TodaysDate As Date = Date.Today

    ' You convert it to string. Since you didn't sepecify the format, it picks up the fromat settings from your PC regional settings. 
    ' Returns 12/08/2014 which means 12-Aug-2014 (in your locale)
    ' You didn't do .ToString, but that's implicit, unless you set OPTION STRICT ON, in which case it will force you to put .ToString
    Dim StringDate As String = TodaysDate

    ' Same argument as above. 
    Dim AnotherStringDate As String = TodaysDate.ToString ' Returns 12/08/2014 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

As for the question `why converting a date to a string changes the order`? The answer is that it doesnt.

When you convert to string, your local culture format is used, as explained by Tim.  That's not teh case with Date literals in VB.

Date literals - values between hashes such as `#02/11/2014#` - are always displayed in InvariantCulture or "m/d/y" pattern.  This is likely because when you wish to create a date using a literal, you **must** specify the Day and Month in that format.  See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy.aspx):

```
Date literals must be in the format #m/d/yyyy# or they are invalid.
```

So, it would make no sense to display the date to you in one pattern but require you to create them using a different pattern.  This is just the way VB works (in part because the legacy functions have no notion of cultures beyond the local one in use).  This is a VB-ism as seen in this VB vs C# date display in Visual Studio:

[image: Culture is set to fr-FR]

The culture is set to fr-FR.

But your strings ultimately represent the same date - they can make a roundtrip:

```
Dim TodaysDate As Date = Date.Today ' Returns #8/12/2014#

Dim AnotherStringDate As String = TodaysDate.ToString

Dim mydt As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(AnotherStringDate)
If mydt = TodaysDate Then
    Console.Beep()
End If
```

It will beep because the same DateTime is created from the string even though it may *display* in the pattern of "d/m/y" for yur culture.